# How do I combine multiple sys_class_name while query?

Tags: https, servicenow

In the path below where I am doing filter on sys_class_name = Generic Application

```
/api/now/table/cmdb_ci?&sysparm_display_value=true&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true&sys_class_name=Generic Application
```

I have multiple `sys_class_name` like Application, Generic Application, ServiceNow Application, Share point, IBM Websphere, Business application, business service, discovered service, web application, web service, web site.

My question is how do I combine all these Sys_Class_Names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually want to use the `sysparm_query` URL parameter with an `IN` condition:
`sysparm_query=sys_class_nameINcmdb_ci_appl,cmdb_ci_appl_generic,...`

The whole URL looks something like this:
`/api/now/table/cmdb_ci?sysparm_query=sys_class_nameINcmdb_ci_appl%2Ccmdb_ci_appl_generic`

***Note***: this is using the actual class name (e.g. cmdb_ci_appl_generic) in place of the class _label_. If you need to look up the name based on the label, go to `/sys_db_object_list.do`.

One easy way to use `sysparm_query` is to just build the list you want in the UI using the normal filter, and then just right-click the breadcrumbs (the blue text above the filter after Running) for the filter, and click **Copy Query**. That can just be pasted in as the `sysparm_query` in the table API.

Comment: Thanks Joey, this URL gave me some idea. and can you pleases explain more on this "One easy way to use sysparm_query is to just build the list you want in the UI using the normal filter, and then just right-click the breadcrumbs (the blue text above the filter after Running) for the filter, and click Copy Query. That can just be pasted in as the sysparm_query in the table API". As i am beginner in to this, need some more details.

Comment: Interactively, in the UI, go to `/cmdb_ci_appl_list.do`, at the top there's a filter. Construct a filter according to what you want to retrieve with your Table API GET request and click `Run`. It will load with some blue text above the filter called "breadcrumbs". Right-click those breadcrumbs and select "Copy Query". This will give you the encoded query version suitable for passing as `sysparm_query` to the Table Rest API.

Answer (score 0):

When you filter on a table you can right click on the filter text and select "copy URL".

https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/london-platform-administration/page/administer/exporting-data/task/t_UseAURLQueryToFilterAListResult.html

Your URL will look something like this:
`/api/now/table/cmdb_ci?&sysparm_display_value=true&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true&sys_class_name=Generic Application&sys_class_name=ServiceNow Application`

Comment: Thanks Gordon. using this technique will only query for the first one. for example in URL suggested , i get only Generic Application but not ServiceNow Application